# Prevent react hooks countdown timer from resetting on click before it ends

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I've created a small quiz app that has a countdown timer. It currently resets when navigated to the next question. However, it is resetting the countdown on first click of the "next question" button before an answer is selected and resets at any point during the countdown. How can I keep the timer from resetting when clicking the "next question" button and before an option is selected?

```
function App() {
  let [points, setPoints] = useState(null);
  let [counter, setCounter] = useState(null);
  let [question, setQuestions] = useState();
  let [is_started, setStart] = useState(false);
  let [isCorrect, setIsCorrect] = useState(false);
  let [hasAnswered, setHasAnswered] = useState();
  let [isChecked, setChecked] = useState(null);
  let [showAnswer, setShowAnswer] = useState(false);
  let [is_end, setEnd] = useState(false);
  let [selectionMade, setSelectionMade] = useState();

  const getData = () => {
    fetch("./questions.json")
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function (data) {
        setQuestions(data);
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  function Countdown({ seconds }) {
    const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(seconds);
    const intervalRef = useRef;

    useEffect(() => {
      intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
        setTimeLeft((t) => t - 1);
      }, 1000);
      return () => clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (timeLeft <= 0) {
        clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
        document.getElementById("false").checked = true;
        nextQuestion();
      }
    }, [timeLeft]);

    return <div>{timeLeft}s left to answer</div>;
  }

  function Answer(props) {
    return (
      <li aria-labelledby="answers-list">
        <label>
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="answer_group"
            className="answer"
            id={`${props.correct}`}
            value={props.answer}
            onChange={checkAnswer}
            checked={isChecked === props.answer}
            disabled={hasAnswered === true ? true : false}
          />
          {props.answer}
        </label>
      </li>
    );
  }

  function checkAnswer(e) {
    let val = e.target.value;
    let ans = question[counter].answers.filter((ans) => ans.value === val)[0];
    ans.correct === true ? setIsCorrect(true) : setIsCorrect(false);
    setHasAnswered(true);
    setChecked(ans.value);
  }

  function Starter(props) {
    return (
      <button className="" onClick={props.start}>
        {is_end ? "Restart" : "Start"}
      </button>
    );
  }

  function Quiz(props) {
    return (
      <div className="quiz-questions">
        <p className="question" id="questions">
          {props.question}
        </p>
        <ul className="answers" role="radiogroup" aria-labelledby="questions">
          {props.children}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }

  function start() {
    setCounter(0);
    setPoints(0);
    setStart(!is_started);
    setEnd(false);
  }

  function nextQuestion() {
    setSelectionMade(true);
    setIsCorrect(false);
    setHasAnswered(false);
    setChecked(null);
    setShowAnswer(false);
    if (document.querySelector('input[name="answer_group"]:checked') == null) {
      setSelectionMade(false);
      return;
    }
    let val = document.querySelector('input[name="answer_group"]:checked')
      .value;
    let answerObj = question[counter].answers.filter(
      (ans) => ans.value === val
    )[0];
    let updated_points = answerObj.correct ? points + 1 : points;
    setPoints(updated_points);
    let nextQuestion = counter + 1;
    if (counter < question.length - 1) {
      setCounter(nextQuestion);
    } else {
      let today = new Date();
      let dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, "0");
      let mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0");
      let yyyy = today.getFullYear();
      let hours = today.getHours();
      let AmOrPm = hours >= 12 ? "pm" : "am";
      hours = hours % 12 || 12;
      let minutes = "" + today.getMinutes();
      let minutesFixed = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
      let finalTime = hours + ":" + minutesFixed + " " + AmOrPm;
      let date = mm + "/" + dd + "/" + yyyy + " at " + finalTime;
      setEnd(!is_end);
      setStart(!is_started);
      setCounter(0);
      console.log({ date: date, score: updated_points });
      setTopScores([...topScores, { date: date, score: updated_points }]);
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="Quiz slide-top"
        style={{ backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,.5)" }}
      >
        {selectionMade === false && hasAnswered === false ? (
          <div className="notification swing-in-top-fwd">
            <p>Please select an answer to continue</p>
          </div>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
        {!is_started ? (
          <div className="quiz-intro">
            <div className="start-intro-wrapper">
              <Starter start={start} />
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className="quick-wrapper slide-in-bottom">
            {!isChecked && <Countdown seconds={15} />}
            <div className="status-details"></div>
            <Quiz question={question[counter].question}>
              <ul>
                {question[counter].answers.map((answer, index, arr) => {
                  return (
                    <Answer
                      key={index}
                      index={index}
                      answer={answer.value}
                      correct={answer.correct}
                    />
                  );
                })}
              </ul>
            </Quiz>
            <div className="answer-controls">
              <div className="answer-buttons">
                <button
                  className="button"
                  onClick={(e) => nextQuestion()}
                >
                  {isChecked === null ? "Select an answer" : "Next question"}
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-feistel-mo557j)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues to fix here... the main problem is that you're defining components inside components - so each time `App` renders (e.g. because of a state change), it will recreate a new `Countdown` component, which will reset the timer.

If you pull the countdown out to its own component -

```
const Countdown = ({ seconds, onNextQuestion }) => {
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(seconds);
  const intervalRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setTimeLeft((t) => t - 1);
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (timeLeft <= 0) {
      clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
      document.getElementById("false").checked = true;
      onNextQuestion();
    }
  }, [timeLeft, onNextQuestion]);

  return <div>{timeLeft}s left to answer</div>;
}
```

And then wire that in:

```
<Countdown seconds={15} onNextQuestion={nextQuestion} />
```

Then it will fix the problem of it resetting when you hit "next". You should ideally do that with *all* the parts of your `App` that could stand-aone.

[Here's an updated CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-rhodes-snqlg5) showing the solution above.

Comment: This is close, but it's skipping the user to the last question if the timer goes out, rather than just the next question.

Comment: Well, I wans't trying to fix everything about your code, just give you an approach of how to start it off. Have you tried refactoring out the other nested components as suggested?

Comment:  I have updated the CodeSandbox to move all the nested components out

Comment: Thanks gerrod, this is REALLY close, appreciate all your help here. I'm just seeing a small issue: triggering the move to the next question if the timer has run out and no option has been selected seems to have been removed. I tried moving the `handleExpired` after the `nextQuestion` function and called it from `handleExpired` function, but no luck.

Comment: Oh.. you just have to separate the handling of a response from the handling of moving to the next question; I've updated the code again.

Answer (score 0):

I would display buttons conditionally and remove `onClick` if `isChecked` is `null`.

```
<div className="answer-buttons">
    {isChecked === null ? 
        <button className="">Select an answer</button>
     
    : 
    
        <button className="" onClick={(e) => nextQuestion()}>
            Next question
        </button>
    }
</div>
```

[Edited Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-vaughan-eosqrx?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: This doesn't account for the "Please select an answer to continue" message that shows if a radio button isn't selected and the user hits the "next question" button.

Comment: The "Select an answer" button is self explanatory so I think it doesn't need that message at all. Just make it disabled if answer is not selected. `<button className="" disabled>Select an answer</button>`

Answer (score -1):

I have updated several parts of your code.
Please have a look [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiz-app-lbkkvv?file=/src/App.js).
Hope this would be helpful for you.

Comment: This is close, but looks like it removes the feature to disable radio buttons and toggle the "Please select an answer to continue" to hidden if a radio button is selected.

Comment: Would you like to make users can select the answer only 1 time?
Once the answer is selected, the others can't be selected?

Comment: Now I updated to remove the warning message on selecting an answer. @Matt

Comment: Yes, it originally disabled the radio buttons if one was selected, so the user only has a set amount of time to answer, and then can't change their selection after the first choice. This solution is almost there, but needs to be able to disable the radio buttons each question after an answer is selected.

Comment: I have updated it as you want. Please check the sandbox link.
But I have a question. If users can select the answer only one time, is there any need to continue the timer after selecting the answer?

Comment: Based on my Codesandbox example in the question, I have the logic in place to turn the timer off if a user has selected a radio button. So that should happen in the answer.

Comment: Aha, you mean once the user selects the answer, the timer should be paused?
I have updated again my sandbox and hope it would be the final solution for you.

Comment: Please do not use this solution. Nesting components (`Answer`, `Countdown`, etc) inside components is an antipattern and will definitely lead to bugs.